# ¿Como hacer un count desde un stored procedure e insertarlos en una tabla?

Tags: sql-server

Buen dia estoy buscando como hacer un count desde un stored procedure y que el resultado se inserte en una tabla se como hacer el count pero nose como hacerlo desde un stored.

SELECT COUNT(Usuario) AS Conteo FROM tbl_Asignaciones

Answer (score 0):

Así tal cual

```
USE [TuBaseDeDatos];  
GO  
CREATE PROCEDURE [nombreStore]   
--Parametros si los necesitas
--@LastName nvarchar(50),     
AS   

-- tus transacciones
insert into [tuTabla] (columna) values (SELECT COUNT(Usuario) AS Conteo FROM tbl_Asignaciones)
```

Si ocupas más información acerca de los procedimientos almacenados dale una revisada a la página de Microsoft 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017